# Logging in spark structured streaming / SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-flink, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to port an Apache Flink application (scala) to Spark structured streaming. The basic job of the app is:

- Read messages from kafka
- Do some transformations / processing
- Output zero or more messages to kafka

During processing, I want to output log messages (general processing info, parsing errors, ...). However - coming from Flink - the processing will be done within one or more `.map` operators which operate on my `Dataset[Node]` / `Dataset[MyCaseClass]` objects. Unfortunately, inside these operators, everything must be serializable, which is not true for my logger (using `scala-logging`).

Thus, when trying to use the logger, I get: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`.

Example:

```
    spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", host + ":" + port)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[String]
      .map(n =>
      {
        // processing here

        log.warn("bla")      // <-- no-go

        <root></root>.asInstanceOf[Node]
      })
      .map(_.toString())
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", host.get + ":" + port.get)
      .option("topic", topic.get)
      .option("checkpointLocation", "myDir")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

What is the recommended way of doing stuff like logging which is not serializable? In Flink there is the option to subclass `RichMapFunction` and similar classes where you can put all the non-serializable stuff, and those will be instantiated per operator / parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce a unserializable objects in spark's map operator like database connection, you can always take the advantage of mapPartition function.

```
mapPartition(iter => {
    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger
    iter.map(row => {
        ....
    })
})
```

Comment: What does this do in terms of parallel processing? E.g. is `iter.map` still processed in parallel on the cluster workers? And is there a flatMap variant too?

Comment: To add to this question, I just added the code as you suggested, and it still throws `NotSerializableException`.